# Extend / override Mapbox-gl 'baselayer' loadTile

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, raster, mapbox-gl-js, wms

Similar to how Leaflet's [guide](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html) shows how to override L.TileLayer's `getTileUrl` method in place of your own (and L.GridLayer's `createTile` method),

I want to know how to extend/override Mapbox-gl's baselayer tiles (as opposed to only using a [tile server URL](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/map-tiles/) to add in custom tiles).

I'm looking to avoid just [adding a layer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addlayer) and instead want to overwrite the baselayer itself.

I saw [this issue discussion](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3186) of customizing RasterTileSource.loadTile and wondered if this was the right direction.

Leaflet's example:

```
L.TileLayer.Kitten = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: function(coords) {
        var i = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 4 );
        return "https://placekitten.com/256/256?image=" + i;
    }
});

L.tileLayer.kitten = function() {
    return new L.TileLayer.Kitten();
}

L.tileLayer.kitten().addTo(map);
```

Comment: I assume you're asking about mapbox gl js instead of mapbox.js because of the tags for the question

Comment: @AndrewHarvey yes! I will make things clearer.

Comment: Have you tried asking in [gis.se]? A different (although overlapping) set of people hang out there.

Comment: @peeebeee Thank you for the advice! Here's that post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303555/extend-override-mapbox-gl-baselayer-loadtile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map.transformRequest` to intercept and modify a tile request. For instance:

```
function addAuthHeaders(url, resourceType) {
    var username = 'me';
    var password = 'password';
    if (resourceType === 'Tile' && url.match('mysite')) {
        return {
            url: url,
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) }
        };
    }
}

var map = mapboxgl.Map({
   …,
   transformRequest: addAuthHeaders
});
```

Note however, that this feature is [poorly documented](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6871).